# MYSQL subquery with groupBy and having - check if "child" has "cousins" and filter out if it does

Tags: mysql, subquery, parent-child

Here's sample database, you can see more detailed database in mysql fiddle at the end of the question:

```
children:
 id, name, age, date_of_birth, favorite_book, parent_id
parents: 
  id, gender, grandparent_id (nullable)
grandparents: 
  id
```

I'd like to construct following query:

Return all favorite_books, sorted by child's date of birth, which don't have grandparents or younger cousins from aunts.

It's a silly example :), I know.

Is this possible to be done in one query?

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
  children.id,
  children.name,
  children.date_of_birth,
  children.favorite_book,
  hasYoungerAuntCousins <-- this is what I don't know how to set up
FROM
  children
ORDER BY
  children.date_of_birth DESC
GROUP BY
  favorite_book
HAVING
 hasYoungerAuntCousins == 0
```

So the result would be something like:

```
2, Joe, 1/1/2010, Basics 3 of MySQL, 0
9, Moe, 1/1/2005, Basics 1 of MySQL, 0
5, Zoe, 1/1/2001, Basics 2 of MySQL, 0
...
```

The `hasYoungerAuntCousins` subquery should return `0` in two scenarios:

- if the `parent` has NULL for `grandparent_id` column
- if the `parent` has `grandparent` and grandparent has daughter (female) - child's aunt - which has children which are younger than the `child` we're 'iterating' through.

Let me know if this makes sense and if I've missed something.

I'm searching for the solution in the meantime and any pointers in comments are also appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a fiddle link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f06d5e

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want me to do? The discussion you point me to is really general. I have described the database and made it as simple as possible, I have stated the request with words as I can't do it in MySQL. I have written expected result. And posted the example code how it should be looking to the extent of my knowledge at this point.

Comment: It's not general at all. It's very specific.

Comment: I have added a link to jsfiddle.  If there's anything else you'd like feel free to tell me.

Comment: Your fiddle data and the expected output is not matching. For eg.,there is no book called `Basics 3 of MySQL` in your fiddle. Please change it

Comment: _"which don't have grandparents or younger cousins from aunts"_ - if both have which should come first? it seems like your expected result there are sorting by those who have grandparents, have cousin(s) and is the younger cousin first.

Comment: @tcadidot0 Sort should be by children.date_of_birth, the `has grandparent` condition, `has younger cousin from aunt` condition should be reflected in `hasYoungerCousins` "custom" response column so that I can filter out those which don't have any `hasYoungerCousins`. So the `hasYoungerCousins` can be either boolean or integer, whichever is easier/more-efficient.
@ArunPalanisamy The fiddle has more data so it should be easier to write query against it. I'll do my best to update the question to be aligned with query provided ASAP (~during the day).

Comment: @tcadidot0 Actually, in ideal solution the `hasYOugerCousin` response column should be either the date_of_birth of "oldest of the younger cousins from an aunt", or NULL (if none). But i simplified it here as it's already rather complex (for me).

Comment: Hi @brnd0 , the best I can come up with is doing a sub-query for parent and grandparent with two times joining on `parents` table. Similarly, I did join the `children` table twice. [Here's how far I get](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9315c02701dac9469078b3af54b562e4) . Can you take a look if its anything close to what you want?